# LINQ - Select complete object with join in entityframework

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I  have a Model called employee

```
[Table("tblemployee")]
public class Employee
{
   public int EmpID;
   public string EmpName;
   [NotMapped]
   public string EmpRole;
}
```

I have another Model of Role

```
[Table("tblrole")]
public class Role
{
public int EmpID;
public string RoleName;
}
```

Now I want a final object of employee which sets RoleName of the Role class to the EmpRole of the Employee class.

```
var result =  from e in Context.Employee 
              join r in Context.Role on e.EmpID equals r.EmpID
              select new Employee {
              EmpID = e.EmpID,        
              EmpName = e.EmpName,
              EmpRole = r.RoleName
              };
```

Here, I don't want to set all the properties of employee class . I just want to set only the emprole property which comes from the role class. Is there other way so that i can select complete employee object at once and only set the EmpRole field? Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only way to solve this is select both Employee and role in table and then apply ToList and then on list apply foreach to set EmpRole in Employee objects and then select that Employee object from the list.

```
var result =  (from e in Context.Employee 
              join r in Context.Role on e.EmpID equals r.EmpID
              select new { Employee = e, Role = r}).ToList();

result.ForEach(d => {d.Employee.EmpRole = d.Role.RoleName;});
var finalResult = result.Select(d => d.Employee);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. but this throws the following error

"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Employee.SetEmpRole(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: Yes, Its working .. thanks Jenish. But my concern is about the performance. Will this approach lags in the performance wise than my approach? Bcoz I think using foreach will consume more time.

Comment: @Alicek There can be performance issues with the list if there is heavy data but Linq to SQL does not provide a way to update entity while selecting. I think the way(`select new Employee...`) you have mentioned in question is great for good performance.

Comment: An article why you should use `foreach` instead of the LINQ equivalent `ForEach` when updating objects: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx